# WebGL: Rendering a lot of objects using different programs

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm learning WebGL now.

I made a simple scene with 10 triangles and when I had increased amount of triangles to 1000 scene started to freeze. I use 3 shaders and 2 program (for emulation real environment). I know I should take out of the render cycle body something but I don't know what.

My code is bellow:

```
function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  context.clear(context.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const currentProgram = i % 2 === 0 ? blueProgram : redProgram;
    context.useProgram(currentProgram);

    const a_Position = context.getAttribLocation(currentProgram, "a_Position");

    const triangleGeometry = getTriangleGeometry(); // returns Float32Array filled with randoms

    const buffer = context.createBuffer();
    context.bindBuffer(context.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);

    context.bufferData(context.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleGeometry, context.STATIC_DRAW);
    context.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Position);
    context.vertexAttribPointer(
      a_Position,
      2,
      context.FLOAT,
      false,
      0,
      0,
    );

    context.drawArrays(context.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
  }
}

requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

Any ideas what I can do for performance optimization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to optimize drawing lots of things but since yoi're just starting the most important is that in general setting up buffers should happen at init time, not render time.

See [Draw multiple models in WebGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57379893/draw-multiple-models-in-webgl)

The code in the question is looking up locations every triangle. it should look up locations as init time.

The code is also creating a new buffer for every triangle. It would be faster to create one buffer and just update it with the new triangle, and of course eventually it will run out of memory creating new buffers.

```js
const context = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');

const vs = `
attribute vec4 a_Position;
void main() {
  gl_Position = a_Position;
}
`;

const redFS = `
precision highp float;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
}
`;

const blueFS = `
precision highp float;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(0, 0, 1, 1);
}
`;

const blueProgram = twgl.createProgram(context, [vs, blueFS]);
const blueProgramInfo = {
  program: blueProgram,
  a_PositionLocation: context.getAttribLocation(blueProgram, "a_Position"),
};

const redProgram = twgl.createProgram(context, [vs, redFS]);
const redProgramInfo = {
  program: redProgram,
  a_PositionLocation: context.getAttribLocation(redProgram, "a_Position"),
};

const buffer = context.createBuffer();

function rand(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

// pre allocate
const triangleData = new Float32Array(6);  // 3 vertices, 2 values per

function getTriangleGeometry() {
  const x = rand(-1, 1);
  const y = rand(-1, 1);
  triangleData[0] = x; 
  triangleData[1] = y;
  triangleData[2] = x + rand(-0.1, 0.1);
  triangleData[3] = y + rand(-0.1, 0.1);
  triangleData[4] = x + rand(-0.1, 0.1);
  triangleData[5] = y + rand(-0.1, 0.1);
  return triangleData;
}

function render() {
  context.clear(context.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    const currentProgramInfo = i % 2 === 0 ? blueProgramInfo : redProgramInfo;
    context.useProgram(currentProgramInfo.program);

    const a_Position = currentProgramInfo.a_PositionLocation;

    const triangleGeometry = getTriangleGeometry(); // returns Float32Array filled with randoms

    context.bindBuffer(context.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    context.bufferData(context.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleGeometry, context.STATIC_DRAW);
    context.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Position);
    context.vertexAttribPointer(
      a_Position,
      2,
      context.FLOAT,
      false,
      0,
      0,
    );

    context.drawArrays(context.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

The code in the question appears to be using 2 programs, one to draw blue and one to draw red. It would probably be faster to have one program with a uniform to choose the color.

```js
const context = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');

const vs = `
attribute vec4 a_Position;
void main() {
  gl_Position = a_Position;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision highp float;
uniform vec4 u_Color;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = u_Color;
}
`;


const program = twgl.createProgram(context, [vs, fs]);
const programInfo = {
  program: program,
  a_PositionLocation: context.getAttribLocation(program, "a_Position"),
  u_ColorLocation: context.getUniformLocation(program, "u_Color"),
};

const buffer = context.createBuffer();

function rand(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

// pre allocate
const triangleData = new Float32Array(6);  // 3 vertices, 2 values per

function getTriangleGeometry() {
  const x = rand(-1, 1);
  const y = rand(-1, 1);
  triangleData[0] = x; 
  triangleData[1] = y;
  triangleData[2] = x + rand(-0.1, 0.1);
  triangleData[3] = y + rand(-0.1, 0.1);
  triangleData[4] = x + rand(-0.1, 0.1);
  triangleData[5] = y + rand(-0.1, 0.1);
  return triangleData;
}

const blue = [0, 0, 1, 1];
const red = [1, 0, 0, 1];

function render() {
  context.clear(context.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  context.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  
  const a_Position = programInfo.a_PositionLocation;
  context.bindBuffer(context.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
  context.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Position);
  context.vertexAttribPointer(
    a_Position,
    2,
    context.FLOAT,
    false,
    0,
    0,
  );

  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    const color = i % 2 === 0 ? blue : red;
    context.uniform4fv(programInfo.u_ColorLocation, color);
   
    const triangleGeometry = getTriangleGeometry(); // returns Float32Array filled with randoms
    context.bufferData(context.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleGeometry, context.STATIC_DRAW);

    context.drawArrays(context.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

It would be significantly faster if you put all the triangles in a single buffer at init time as well as each triangle's vertex colors in a buffer at init time and just draw them with a single draw call at render time. If you wanted random triangles every frame then it will still be faster to create one buffer at init time, fill out N random triangles in a single buffer, and then draw them all in one draw call.

```js
const context = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');

const vs = `
attribute vec4 a_Position;
attribute vec4 a_Color;

varying vec4 v_Color;

void main() {
  gl_Position = a_Position;
  v_Color = a_Color;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision highp float;
varying vec4 v_Color;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = v_Color;
}
`;


const program = twgl.createProgram(context, [vs, fs]);
const programInfo = {
  program: program,
  a_PositionLocation: context.getAttribLocation(program, "a_Position"),
  a_ColorLocation: context.getAttribLocation(program, "a_Color"),
  u_ColorLocation: context.getUniformLocation(program, "u_Color"),
};

const positionBuffer = context.createBuffer();
const colorBuffer = context.createBuffer();

function rand(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

const numTriangles = 1000;

const positionData = new Float32Array(numTriangles * 3 * 2);  
const colorData = new Float32Array(numTriangles * 3 * 4);

const blue = [0, 0, 1, 1];
const red = [1, 0, 0, 1];

// the color data does not change so fill it out at init time
for (let i = 0; i < numTriangles; ++i) {
  const offset = i * 4;
  colorData.set(i % 2 === 0 ? blue : red, offset);
}
context.bindBuffer(context.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
context.bufferData(context.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorData, context.STATIC_DRAW);

function getTriangleGeometry() {
  for (let i = 0; i < numTriangles; ++i) {
    const offset = i * 3 * 2;  // 3 verts per tri, 2 values per ver
    const x = rand(-1, 1);
    const y = rand(-1, 1);
    positionData[offset    ] = x; 
    positionData[offset + 1] = y;
    positionData[offset + 2] = x + rand(-0.1, 0.1);
    positionData[offset + 3] = y + rand(-0.1, 0.1);
    positionData[offset + 4] = x + rand(-0.1, 0.1);
    positionData[offset + 5] = y + rand(-0.1, 0.1);
  }
  return positionData;
}


function render() {
  context.clear(context.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  context.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  
  const a_Position = programInfo.a_PositionLocation;
  context.bindBuffer(context.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  const triangleGeometry = getTriangleGeometry(); // returns Float32Array filled with randoms
  context.bufferData(context.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleGeometry, context.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
  context.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Position);
  context.vertexAttribPointer(
    a_Position,
    2,
    context.FLOAT,
    false,
    0,
    0,
  );
  
  const a_Color = programInfo.a_ColorLocation;
  context.bindBuffer(context.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
  context.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Color);
  context.vertexAttribPointer(
    a_Color,
    4,
    context.FLOAT,
    false,
    0,
    0,
  );

  context.drawArrays(context.TRIANGLES, 0, numTriangles * 3);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Drawing a bunch of random triangles every frame like you have above is arguably an exception. The majority of WebGL apps draw 3D models created in a modeling package so it's far more common to just put data in a buffer once at init time (like data for a cube, a sphere, a car, a human, a tree) and then draw it at render time.

Also be aware that GPUs can only draw so many pixels so if your triangles are large (like the size of the entire screen) you'll only be able to draw 10 to a few 100). A 1920x1080 screen is about 2 millon pixels. So every fullscreen triangle would also be about 2 million pixels. Drawing 1000 of them is 2000 * 2 million or 4 billion pixels. At 60 frames a second 240 billion pixels. A medium high end GPU can only draw 10billion a second and that's a theoretical max so at best it could do that at ~2 frames a second.

Most 3D apps draw a scene where most of the triangles are far away and small. They also use the depth buffer and draw opaque objects front to back so pixels that are in back don't get drawn.

Comment: Can you tell about purpose of **bindBuffer**? Also I have not any understanding about **enableVertexAttribArray**. And in case I have several programs should I sort my objects for minimizing calls **useProgram** in render cycle? Many thanks! If you take sometime for asking on these questions it will be cool!

Comment: The purpose of `bindBuffer` is to [attach a buffer to a named internal state variable inside WebGL](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/resources/webgl-state-diagram.html). The purpose of `enableVertexAttribArray` is to [specify for a particular vertex attribute whether or not that attribute uses a constant value or gets updated per vertex shader interation from values stored in a buffer](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-attributes.html).